# Is there an API to read Inbox including mail in subfolders in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Right now I can use these APIs to get or track mails in Inbox root folder.

```
GET /me/mailfolders/Inbox/messages
GET /me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages/delta
```

Is there an API that I can read all mails in Inbox including mail in subfolders in Inbox? Thanks

[image]

Comment: There isn't a 'mailbox' `delta`. I would expect everything to come into the Inbox and then get _moved_ elsewhere. It seems like that should leave a trace in your inbox's delta (maybe a `@removed`?).

Comment: Thanks Marc. However I hope there is an API that I can use to sync the whole Inbox including subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I've taken is to do a sequence of requests:

1. Find all descendant folders of the Inbox. To do this I list all Mail Folders then user `parentFolderId` to figure out which ones are descendants.
2. Sync each descendant folder (/$batch is helpful here).

Hope that helps!